# What phonotactical constraints are commonly used by conlangers?

Tags: conlang-creation, phonology

I'm continuing development of *Der Spracherfinder* (to help you fellow conlangers), and I want to know which phonotactical constraints are most common and helpful to conlangers. For example: forbid sonorants clustering with obstruents in coda position.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a comprehensive survey that could tell you what's "common" (especially considering that the vast majority of conlangs are probably private matters).  Is your question intending to be an informal survey?

For conlangs intended to resemble natural languages, I would suggest:

- Looking at the constraints in natural languages with a similar phonology.
- Speaking possible words out loud and trying to reduce the effort required to articulate.

For conlangs not intended to resemble natural languages, especially those used in fictional settings by non-human speakers, anything goes.